# how to make windows button behave as website button

Tags: delphi, paypal, indy

Please forgive what I'm sure is a simple problem, but I've searched for ages and can't figure it out.

I want to enable feature upgrades from within my program. When the user presses a button on my form I want a browser to launch and go directly to the paypal site. It would be like they pressed the PayPal provided "Buy Now" button on my web page.

I know that I can launch the browser on a particular page using ShellExecute, but I don't think I can issue a POST through that can I?

I think I need to do an HTTPRequest, and as a Rad Studio user that defaults to the Indy TIdHTTPRequest component. All of the examples and documentation I've found are about capturing the output programmatically though, and I just want the browser to launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I wanted isn't possible...

I've confirmed that I can't do a POST through the ShellExecute method, and that the HTTPRequest method is only intended for capturing the output.

It may be that what I really need to do is dig into the paypal api and process the whole thing within my app. Not sure that is even possible though, and its probably more effort than the task is worth.

cheers

Comment: Indy doesn't have an HTTPRequest component.  It has an TIdHTTP component instead.  It sends a single request and gets a response back (not counting redirects and multi-step authentications, which it handles internally).  To interact with PayPal, you just need to send multiple requests as needed. You can certainly do that with TIdHTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Rather then launching the web browser as a separate process, you can use a `TWebBrowser` or `TEmbeddedWB` component to place a web browser inside your app itself, then you can send `POST` requests with it, display the result within your app's UI, even capture the returned HTML if needed, manipulate the browser's DOM interfaces, etc.